# Ubuntu does not detect Windows on installation

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on a partition next to Windows, but the "Install next to Windows" option does not appear.

I have already tried two things that are recommended to do to make Ubuntu find Windows:

Disable fast startup
Execute the chkdsk commands

But it still doesn't work, it's weird, because I have already installed Ubuntu and other distributions in the past, in a separate partition and I didn't have this problem, always appeared that option "Install next to Windows".

What else could I try?

PS: I use UEFI, and it's a GPT partition.
Isn't a dynamic partition
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uYXW.jpg

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395816/edit) and include the following information. Does this computer have BIOS or UEFI (alternately, MBR or GPT)? Does it use [Windows Dynamic partition](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=windows+dynamic+partition&ia=web)? Finally, boot the computer with the Ubuntu Installation USB and select **Try Ubuntu** option. Open the app **Gparted**. Select the internal drive where Windows is installed. Take a screenshot of the Gparted window, upload to imgur.com and add a link to the screenshot to your question.

Comment: During installation choose 'something else' and install Ubuntu in the unallocated part.

Comment: You should also disable Fast Startup in Windows, a must when dual-booting. Fast Startup is a hybrid hibernation and can result in Windows partitions not being read by installer and consequently the install alongside option not being offered.